# Could someone please explain this java Swing code?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have recently just started Awt and Swing in Java and there is this code of ActionListener

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
```

NOW, The things that i know -
We are supposed to pass an object of the class the constructor of which has the above code defined. Usually , I passed 'this' thus giving the object of current class as arguement.

Now the above code contains 'java.awt.event.ActionListener()'. What is that supposed to mean ?? In short can someone just explain the whole code mentioned above completely ? Would be kind of you . I could not find this exact question, the ones which were already asked seem to have understood this basic concept which i am stuck on, So they just went about other complex doubts of theirs.

Comment: Here is oracle's tutorial that migth help you understand actionListeners: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: But that still doesnt clear my doubt ! I am stuck between passing 'this' as the arguement to the addActionListener();  and what is passed above . 'this' is an instance of current class but what have been passed above is not so. I hope u get my question...! ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a new ActionListener:

```
new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
  }
}
```

And add it to your Button:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(..);
```

It is the same as you create a new class implements the `ActionListener` interface and add this to the button.

Comment: Ok, i get it a little. But then , what does jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);          mean?? Cause , we just define our statements in the function body of actionPerformed(); and i dont know what this statement mean !  And after creating a new ActionListener() do we pass 'this' to jButton1.addActionListener(); ??

Comment: @KirtyBhushan You see to be using Netbeans form editor. It allows you to attach a number of "event handlers" to controls, it does this by creating a single ActionListener and then calling each method you specify in order, reducing the number listeners actually attached to the button, but allowing you to extend functionality. Basically, all the ActionListener is doing is call the jButtonActionPerformed method, passing the ActionEvent to it.

Comment: @KirtyBhushan The mechanism by which the ActionListener is created is know as an anonymous class, which allows you to provide the implementation of (in this case) the ActionListener interface without actually needing to first declare a separate class definition...

Comment: @KirtyBhushan jButton1ActionPerformed is a method which is called. it must be defined in the actual class. Where do you pass `this` i can not see it in your code snipped, so i can not explain it.

Comment: @Jens  YES!! It is defined as     # private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  tfUser.setText("");
  jPasswordField1.setText("");  
 }  #   And i almost got what you tried to explain. Thanks for that ! Now there is just one thing and i will try to be as clear as possible. If we implement the ActionListener , we can pass 'this' to addActionListener cause any instance of current class can use the  method of  ActionListener interface . Am i right ??? And if we dont implement it, we have to use the method which i asked

Comment: and which you explained(creating a new ActionListener and then add it to button, right?? Plus, we HAVE TO override the actionPeformed method   and we can now call any other method or statment in its body(ActionEvent instance have to be passed to actionPerformed). Now, am i right in all this ??? Thanks in advance AND THANKs @MadProgrammer .You too helped buddy !

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a code that make a new a new action listener from the package **java.awt.event**
and then add an action for it but probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating an anonymous ActionListener which is good if you only need to use it for jbutton1. If you needed it for multiple buttons, you could create the listener class and give it a name to use for all the buttons you need, like this:

```
public class myListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if( ((JButton) e.getSource()) == jButton1 ) jButton1ActionPerformed(e);
        else if( ((JButton) e.getSource()) == jButton2 ) jButton2ActionPerformed(e);
    }
}//end listener class
```

And add a listener to all your buttons:

```
jButton1.addActionListener(new myListener());
jButton2.addActionListener(new myListener());
```

This talks a little bit about it: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/GUI/events/anonymous_listener.html